# pygame sprite appears to stretch/grow instead of move along x-axis

Tags: python, pygame, sprite

What I'm trying to do is make a green box that moves along the x-axis of the screen. This is what the online tutorial tells me to do:

```
class Player(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

     def __init__(self):
          pygame.sprite.Sprite.__init__(self)
          self.image = pygame.Surface((50, 50))
          self.image.fill((0, 255, 0))
          self.rect = self.image.get_rect()
          self.rect.center = (80, 80)

     def update(self):
          self.rect.x += 5
```

But what I end up with is a rectangle that grows along the x-axis, rather than moving along the x axis.

Why doesn't this code move the sprite as intended?

Comment: Are you clearing the display each frame, before you draw?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've to clear the display in every frame, e.g. by [`.fill()`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html#pygame.Surface.fill):

```py
screen.fill(0)
```

If you don't clear the display, then the rectangle is continuously drawn on top of the previous rectangle (displaced by 5):

```
+---+---+--------+
|1  |2  |3       |
|   |   |        |
|   |   |        |
+---+---+--------+
```